# How to light a Hearthmaster gas fireplace

Tags: fireplace

I just moved into a new house I went to turn on the gas for the fireplace using the key yet I still can't light the fireplace.  There's nothing showing me where to turn on the gas flow to the hearthmaster gas fire place.  We have a natural gas oven which is working fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: Tried checking the web go see if an instruction manuall is available for download?

Comment: Might it be controlled by a wall thermostat?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a thermocouple and gas valve - the thermocouple senses when the fire goes out and turns the gas off. Probably a pilot lite also. Check for a diagram online, here is a link to a youtube example:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=61DP2Spo4qk

second link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CvL_fAFRIW8